# iOS : App crash when use 2 frameworks (Quickblox +Twilio )at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, twilio, quickblox

I am facing a crash:

> exc_bad_access(code =1, address =0x4)

in Xcode when I use Twilio (For App to Mobile call) in my app with Quickblox(For App to App audio/video call). But when I use only twilio then my app works fine.
Could I use Twilio with Quickblox in my app?

> Cases : When I use only one framework either Twilio or Quickblox then
>   app runs fine(no any crash comes). But when I use both framework
>   Twilio and Quickblox then app crashes. Any suggestion will be great.
>   Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post entire crash stack trace for others to review and provide solution  as only mentioning exc_bad_access is not enough.